# Pandas converting numbers to strings - unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file-conversion

It seems that there is no way of obtaining input tables (from html / xls / etc files) to DataFrame objects as it is 1-to-1 without any field conversions applied internally by pandas.

Assume the following html table saved with the extension of .xls file, how would we get the same representation of this table in Python memory with DataFrame object?

The content of "test_file.xls":

```
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="tabHead" x:autofilter="all">Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tDetail">1.320,00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tDetail">600,00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

**(1) Straightforward reading of the file**

Processing code:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_html('test_file.xls')
print(df[0])
print(df[0].dtypes)
```

Output:

```
     Number
0      1.32
1  60000.00

Number    float64
dtype: object
```

As we can see the numbers were converter to float64 with some predefined logic. I think this logic includes locales settings, maybe some rules inside pandas, etc. Specifying string convertors directly doesn't allow to obtain the initial values.

**(2) Applying str function as a convertor for each dimension**

Processing code:

```
converters = {column_name: str for column_name in df[0].dtypes.index}
df = pandas.read_html(f, converters = converters)
print(df[0])
print(df[0].dtypes)
```

Output:

```
    Number
0  1.32000
1    60000

Number    object
dtype: obje
```

**Obviously, the expected output of this problem is:**

```
     Number
0  1.320,00
1    600,00
```

There could be cases when **one** file contains numbers typed in **different** formats (American / European / etc). This numbers differs with decimal mark, thousand mark, etc. So the logical way to handle such files will be to extract the data "as it is" in strings and perform parsing with regexps / other modules separately for each row. Is there a way how to do it in pandas? And are there any other approaches how to handle such file's processing? Thanks guys!

**Remarks:**
Specification of "decimal" and "thousands" parameters for pandas.read_* doesn't look like a reliable solution because it is appled for all fields. Quick example: it can treat date fields in **"02.2017"** format as numbers and convert it to **"022017"**.

Comment: I guess `read_html` should take a `dtype` argument like `read_csv` does.

Comment: @Goyo, unfortunately it doesn't ... There is [an issue on Pandas GitHub and it is still open](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10534)

Comment: The input value of `<td class="tDetail">,,,2,,,,5,,,,,5,,,,0,,,.,,,7,,,7,,,</td>` (mind the dote!) also converts to `2550.77`.

Comment: @Goyo, for Pandas 0.21.0 it gives me `TypeError: read_html() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'`

Comment: I removed the `processing` tag since it is for the programming language called `Processing`, and is not a generic tag for programs which involve file processing. Please read a tag description before using it.

Comment: John, thank a lot! Sorry for confusion with this!

Comment: @MaxU I know, what I meant is that it should be fixed.

Comment: The workaround if you have `100.000,00` formatted numerical values and `01.12.2017` dates is the following: using `decimal = ','`,  `thousands = '.'` and passing the convertor dictionary that maps all columns to str: `converters = {column_name: str for column_name in df[0].dtypes.index}` in read_html call. So the numbers will be correct (according to this format) and dates won't be changed to something like `1122017` (remember that leading zero might be removed!)

Answer (score 2):

You must specify your thousands and decimal separator. this worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd

html = """
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="tabHead" x:autofilter="all">Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tDetail">1.320,00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tDetail">600,00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
"""

df = pd.read_html(html, decimal=",", thousands=".")
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
import pandas as pd


with open('test_file.xls') as f:
    raw_html = f.read()


raw_html = raw_html.replace('"tDetail">', """tDetail">'""").replace('</td>', "'</td>")


df = pd.read_html(raw_html)
```

Returns

```
       Number
0  '1.320,00'
1    '600,00'
```